# Contour plot other than contour lines with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have generated the contour plot with my data [Data to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MqDc.png). The output looks like [contour lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHBht.png). I am now trying to fill the contour plot with colors. There is a previous post about it
http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/07/maps-contour-plots-with-labels.html
and I have followed the instructions and modified as:

```
 set xrange [0:32]
 set yrange [0:32]
 set table 'test.dat'
 splot "contour.dat"
 unset table

 set contour base
 set cntrparam level incremental 0, 0.1, 1
 unset surface
 set table 'cont.dat'
 splot "contour.dat"
 unset table

 reset
 set xrange [0:32]
 set yrange [0:32]
 unset key
 set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
 p 'test.dat' with image, 'cont.dat' w l lt -1 lw 1.5
```

But my plot has this appearance [after new code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkeNB.png). The gnuplot shows the warning and the output message is

```
 warning: Cannot contour non grid data. Please use "set dgrid3d".
 warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

I have set it there but still the appearance does not change.

Now the question is which option or command is missing or should be used to get the colored filled contour map? I am also checking the book https://www.manning.com/books/gnuplot-in-action-second-edition
but still could not find the commands for that kind of plot.

The data is

```
0.9999      0.982523158 0.891048477 0.583411178 0.235163401 0.040130025 1.00E-05    1.00E-05    1.00E-05    0.035682725 0.005428697 0.020932041 0.029782838 0.022353315 0.01152723  1.00E-05    0.002663218 0.004234385 0.004785793 0.00412414  1.00E-05    1.00E-05    0.000580796 0.025190766 0.19110765  0.507916237 0.821045769 0.976541983 0.979832098 0.9999      0.944161278 0.720159779
0.9999      0.973067478 0.824509858 0.515498258 0.196714659 0.02215662  0.001930433 0.031876894 0.033140536 0.029554456 1.00E-05    0.007143897 0.001566911 1.00E-05    0.037378856 0.005977127 0.013283047 0.022265608 0.01827373  0.007627014 0.000167961 0.035911698 0.036163972 0.007598274 0.102779682 0.342304319 0.629002943 0.835660968 0.915237217 0.902408744 0.785948515 0.542827623
0.851954648 0.800884814 0.615992685 0.342731798 0.104482546 0.011840285 0.029469663 1.00E-05    1.00E-05    1.00E-05    1.00E-05    1.00E-05    0.026375308 1.00E-05    0.02072085  0.074807389 0.138750288 0.16703943  0.139979059 0.076340868 0.018197414 0.002778291 1.00E-05    0.001484506 0.029011079 0.156574172 0.354646905 0.536402725 0.63287085  0.618777015 0.493896783 0.291684717
0.51718903  0.466202811 0.319405608 0.140714994 0.025865626 0.036049337 1.00E-05    1.00E-05    0.03219016  0.033409853 0.033651765 0.03030058  0.031169542 0.021333766 0.129627995 0.296292679 0.435977458 0.487461936 0.428265336 0.281984362 0.118289641 0.018805742 0.003774484 0.034996285 0.00425743  0.035138289 0.120141077 0.217615538 0.277655039 0.264475233 0.185260535 0.084939547
0.182475138 0.154880431 0.086665517 0.024041383 0.005459017 1.00E-05    0.000300364 0.043848781 0.044965735 0.007238176 0.005801704 1.00E-05    0.007316639 0.101489626 0.33036401  0.593649916 0.775870253 0.830501755 0.762936865 0.563999169 0.294543097 0.083684955 0.006607316 0.003366544 1.00E-05    0.003892168 0.016420963 0.037723106 0.052984926 0.044641457 0.024308647 0.046347832
0.027792756 0.020341271 0.014089586 0.009340287 0.04140216  0.040595247 0.005715897 0.011470496 0.01468797  0.016993293 0.018003174 0.009720034 0.028838961 0.197733013 0.51363769  0.817260396 0.96815601  0.998483647 0.958424324 0.78195343  0.462313354 0.163142698 0.0210613   1.00E-05    0.002384908 0.004043211 0.004081986 0.001265788 0.000120176 0.033084563 0.030668279 1.00E-05
0.007059003 0.003655667 0.011870197 0.009394357 0.005385329 0.039035408 0.006462258 0.011999697 0.019544602 0.016464843 0.012776067 0.007972404 0.045957337 0.247832319 0.599513951 0.899196477 0.984366576 0.9999      0.977961991 0.862585385 0.541393207 0.205948244 0.033390224 0.004231    0.004866654 0.003014723 0.003623085 0.00187932  1.00E-05    1.00E-05    1.00E-05    1.00E-05
0.008747924 0.006830015 0.014403608 0.025626224 0.023730515 0.016681035 0.010401817 0.014135891 0.009650236 0.011045515 0.011609941 0.008865041 0.04281916  0.224693147 0.556126845 0.862259058 0.988832111 0.9999      0.980062911 0.820917478 0.498814169 0.184628171 0.028344465 0.003697355 0.0037474   0.003280804 0.003662558 0.002633438 0.000490997 0.00246968  0.02823553  0.031421351
0.015944971 0.04531812  0.109587044 0.175429872 0.199666866 0.165080497 0.094843153 0.03467632  0.01092787  0.010232922 0.011397636 0.009907805 0.026496074 0.144796819 0.401124894 0.68543129  0.862253462 0.906029432 0.840654843 0.641230414 0.352902499 0.114138909 0.014896994 0.003670062 0.003785455 0.0035948   0.006942384 0.019376903 0.037414369 0.042572183 0.027487039 0.008993108
0.061420875 0.191851435 0.367956007 0.505609288 0.550796197 0.485835936 0.330221357 0.153196235 0.041624218 0.010933452 0.009038844 0.008733224 0.012950915 0.060160921 0.201838898 0.399528134 0.554915502 0.604065512 0.53346247  0.365595104 0.170839767 0.042062655 0.005800244 0.003327563 0.00371733  0.009738636 0.050356042 0.13523019  0.220692933 0.253781775 0.212002473 0.121937801
0.169124299 0.423804661 0.681681444 0.835285937 0.872513269 0.810127664 0.619175791 0.342977126 0.114793875 0.020826769 0.008997988 0.00962584  0.00943097  0.017205879 0.059803286 0.143893602 0.225014755 0.252902045 0.211994667 0.125540339 0.04501628  0.009148389 0.004495928 0.004163555 0.006661964 0.048835929 0.186616289 0.383676092 0.545001152 0.605108418 0.544221317 0.37670716
0.294097103 0.629055541 0.893594948 0.988618721 0.976685668 0.972155199 0.822312358 0.51187419  0.198799352 0.037843722 0.009223186 0.010018614 0.010570771 0.009817808 0.013077596 0.026364956 0.043959741 0.049992095 0.037978171 0.018742963 0.007249969 0.00437049  0.003896394 0.003916297 0.018225634 0.128715806 0.377101189 0.661694419 0.848356881 0.903221361 0.848593119 0.659519323
0.364028753 0.725043955 0.963516567 0.9999      0.9999      0.9999      0.890867525 0.585373413 0.240701881 0.048712789 0.009715081 0.010337255 0.011821464 0.010977836 0.00884407  0.007384053 0.006941438 0.00630658  0.005438564 0.004515368 0.004670137 0.004842314 0.004975833 0.005249804 0.035841033 0.206825734 0.529812898 0.842482465 0.985394709 0.9999      0.986103824 0.843048755
0.341698481 0.690877008 0.936292264 0.979587411 0.986559237 0.987414747 0.84947266  0.539185146 0.214414917 0.041205841 0.008496801 0.009374307 0.011055057 0.010613996 0.008663892 0.006742032 0.005496349 0.004621427 0.00435038  0.004308883 0.004898404 0.00492433  0.005048379 0.005700701 0.043520492 0.234012464 0.579704002 0.889983604 0.982379619 0.993375828 0.982781739 0.89211904
0.238943568 0.531411789 0.790156262 0.918891468 0.941393619 0.874936334 0.679764686 0.388636278 0.1358585   0.022754611 0.007026365 0.008177227 0.008829201 0.008601284 0.009976017 0.015894554 0.023338217 0.024192646 0.016927589 0.008711167 0.005387796 0.005012774 0.005178965 0.005622369 0.033675965 0.194301997 0.507994163 0.822325851 0.975621338 0.9999      0.977153793 0.827093899
0.112917671 0.298927953 0.505044977 0.642557395 0.670211274 0.583949224 0.40398185  0.196169759 0.054057823 0.009466147 0.006148842 0.006808958 0.007174796 0.012870056 0.042540005 0.100975644 0.154931158 0.167143595 0.129137136 0.066511122 0.020342182 0.006284195 0.005217972 0.005392434 0.017571215 0.112878898 0.341161939 0.617612625 0.808785254 0.868113712 0.812688852 0.625567763
0.031596957 0.103478148 0.207591289 0.289162543 0.305371931 0.248806895 0.147621325 0.055623683 0.01277838  0.005999178 0.006314731 0.006303963 0.010407127 0.051789151 0.171390509 0.334244042 0.458275824 0.485704194 0.405401061 0.251352012 0.100110162 0.0213025   0.006278242 0.005891383 0.00872238  0.041567658 0.155426681 0.331548597 0.484359485 0.544393063 0.490187745 0.340368577
0.009812002 0.019350284 0.042311949 0.065272806 0.068471713 0.048752552 0.022908803 0.008573715 0.005643325 0.006265362 0.006482173 0.006727634 0.027518127 0.145281122 0.382692454 0.639072376 0.798863426 0.830046382 0.73635766  0.518132334 0.252706067 0.06932794  0.011587493 0.00680223  0.007289484 0.01172333  0.039397147 0.103830088 0.175189631 0.207447811 0.180088402 0.109516953
0.009142008 0.007468396 0.007092918 0.007194917 0.006352574 0.005314441 0.003463252 0.004980697 0.005780664 0.006724703 0.006673399 0.008850412 0.056529771 0.251919418 0.575369384 0.859645057 0.981858001 0.992720926 0.944934992 0.737904644 0.408497772 0.13349894  0.021532254 0.007498621 0.007829857 0.007292342 0.007970426 0.014446539 0.026377013 0.033924747 0.028655555 0.016063671
0.009493354 0.007487699 0.005673333 0.004660324 0.00410047  0.004871314 0.003964493 0.005073033 0.005668034 0.006521753 0.00601545  0.010009445 0.074928356 0.310027303 0.666725517 0.937368096 0.9999      0.994075034 0.997317166 0.833284025 0.490142335 0.170819653 0.027049691 0.007033414 0.007243675 0.006857442 0.005502501 0.004526947 0.004108371 0.004971427 0.004848677 0.004889328
0.007876022 0.006759912 0.00717937  0.013239625 0.02415985  0.030297081 0.024833195 0.014292012 0.007466304 0.005779199 0.005200008 0.008393379 0.066215712 0.288317689 0.63517724  0.910783797 0.9999      0.987502098 0.984117087 0.804978751 0.463714893 0.155928261 0.021877568 0.005602731 0.005886427 0.005694104 0.0048815   0.004930487 0.004682147 0.004231205 0.004275928 0.004735956
0.0056793   0.008717832 0.033348695 0.096245107 0.166988358 0.198265982 0.17100119  0.103037934 0.038559206 0.009199286 0.004414635 0.005169448 0.037380451 0.198670276 0.489754512 0.770027554 0.919724201 0.947441887 0.871499536 0.64989922  0.340568055 0.098821795 0.01130737  0.003546481 0.004720721 0.006154507 0.013063447 0.025169988 0.032513034 0.027053789 0.014876871 0.006805564
0.005399518 0.030665082 0.137397993 0.313426284 0.470733052 0.534556922 0.480739225 0.331841001 0.155967149 0.038968056 0.00604349  0.003938463 0.012501117 0.09051998  0.278185529 0.502917711 0.658355235 0.692251425 0.596928407 0.397805696 0.176612808 0.038222911 0.005033068 0.003540855 0.006838166 0.03257234  0.097642868 0.170883475 0.205429948 0.179651017 0.109581227 0.040729673
0.010464047 0.089392697 0.307689736 0.590817085 0.796078093 0.862947293 0.808781019 0.620181093 0.344097408 0.112806071 0.01465626  0.002951788 0.004174869 0.021620514 0.096433613 0.215857934 0.314494191 0.33739347  0.273552637 0.157177284 0.053251193 0.008725909 0.004293321 0.004695077 0.032790735 0.144589045 0.321823591 0.478307255 0.543087315 0.492276934 0.344165668 0.16477652
0.019903551 0.15586652  0.458005252 0.789344524 0.967306644 0.9999      0.97586068  0.825635027 0.512459492 0.19670971  0.032322867 0.004688928 0.004948534 0.004908328 0.015300786 0.04536029  0.078977855 0.088160206 0.065496559 0.030520343 0.009138938 0.004058564 0.003786815 0.013334218 0.10349762  0.328317459 0.606110839 0.803233578 0.868191128 0.816455176 0.631927813 0.356714499
0.025474633 0.182659314 0.513715197 0.847785132 0.975608287 0.9999      0.983450071 0.891000838 0.582872094 0.236365621 0.041208205 0.000293117 0.000691955 0.001940839 0.00495226  0.006267567 0.008984487 0.010145872 0.00841063  0.006030428 0.005042839 0.004840027 0.004990931 0.030782825 0.185129712 0.493278876 0.810826754 0.972668377 0.9999      0.978793074 0.831697921 0.521932075
0.01930045  0.151675481 0.449921653 0.780316009 0.962401217 0.9999      0.979257323 0.836538188 0.526192992 0.203425154 0.028384391 1.00E-05    1.00E-05    1.00E-05    0.00222998  0.004214155 0.00414953  0.004464453 0.004975862 0.005636715 0.005668266 0.005625953 0.006310905 0.042400725 0.224412221 0.562846833 0.878147251 0.980618598 0.994282176 0.982958967 0.89205072  0.585705686
0.009393489 0.082953937 0.294570816 0.574926233 0.784437523 0.859967111 0.816787759 0.636957337 0.35987384  0.115559502 0.010361086 0.031627737 0.028754766 1.00E-05    1.00E-05    0.0035418   0.005415645 0.005011286 0.005139752 0.005820283 0.006035461 0.00591033  0.006297403 0.035844481 0.196864775 0.509806148 0.825292285 0.979173578 0.9999      0.980606861 0.834718733 0.525124046
0.004053607 0.024501591 0.123408952 0.295250339 0.455955234 0.5293671   0.485136725 0.33970497  0.15744634  0.032398427 1.00E-05    1.00E-05    0.031507764 0.028527143 1.00E-05    0.001117528 0.005264872 0.004990459 0.005081482 0.005428315 0.005760736 0.005683794 0.005443788 0.018715894 0.119613748 0.35466468  0.634547526 0.82482734  0.882181273 0.826773867 0.640614453 0.362533937
0.002655957 0.006026136 0.023219304 0.080905349 0.151642055 0.186936612 0.164375467 0.097117732 0.031109035 0.004470864 0.038065762 1.00E-05    1.00E-05    0.035845328 0.006838627 0.026699524 0.039303163 0.031707646 0.017428789 0.007706403 0.005259594 0.004961271 0.004695013 0.007083378 0.043203893 0.167342754 0.352999366 0.50892877  0.567034911 0.508447251 0.353338273 0.166522149
0.005188791 0.003646668 0.000647874 0.007495457 0.014312906 0.023370868 0.019349891 0.015909783 0.013297987 0.004716524 0.042342679 0.039783293 0.003423272 0.03421355  0.106497288 0.187641421 0.220157719 0.190241303 0.117970241 0.045979037 0.010652597 0.00457506  0.004287649 0.004229215 0.008504538 0.040953111 0.113491551 0.18752673  0.217295922 0.184450903 0.105884292 0.031660304
0.004479522 0.004410448 0.007302065 0.004126552 1.00E-05    0.035801097 0.008699818 0.011939786 0.013714012 0.009248864 0.002560286 0.038098888 0.037908848 0.164841406 0.353482222 0.502417768 0.557273044 0.503049358 0.358246216 0.179673059 0.050754213 0.00738319  0.003720885 0.003715687 0.003478652 0.005359569 0.008438204 0.018563383 0.024121383 0.018956877 0.009237453 1.00E-05
```

Comment: Please post the data as text, not as image.

Comment: @theozh. The data is 32*32 matrix. I do not find how I could attach the data file here. If there is any way and I miss it please let me know. I will be happy to share it here.

Comment: Edit the question, paste the data as text and format it as code.

Comment: @theozh please find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the request...  Were you asking for a smoothed contour plot where the pm3d colors correspond to discrete contour ranges?

```
set view map
set xrange [*:*] noextend
set yrange [*:*] noextend
set pm3d interpolate 9,9
set palette maxcolors 10
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10

splot 'matrix.dat' matrix with pm3d notitle
```

[image]

It's hard to get smooth contour edges when the matrix resolution is only 32x32.  It's maybe a bit better if you back off to only 5 contour levels:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. Paraview and Visit -- these two visualization tools are widely used for this type of output. It is great the gnuplot can produce the same with high quality.

Comment: If I have the same output but in vtk file format, is it still possible to use gnuplot?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (gnuplot>=5.0.3).
Plot your file, e.g. into a datablock `$Contour` via `splot FILE matrix`.
Then plot your file `matrix with image` and the contour lines in a for-loop.
Maybe there are better solutions.

**Code:** (your data saved as file `SO70759953.dat`)

```
### plot matrix with contours
reset session

FILE = 'SO70759953.dat'

set size square
set xrange [0:31]
set yrange [0:31]

set contour base
set cntrparam level incremental 0, 0.2, 1.0
set table $Contour
    splot FILE matrix
unset table

set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
set key out title "Levels"

plot FILE matrix with image notitle, \
     for [i=1:*] $Contour index i w l lt i lw 1.5 ti columnhead(3)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have gnuplot version 5.4.0 or later, you can use the following slightly tricky method to get beautiful output.

In this version, the drawing of surfaces by splot is smoothly cropped over a range of zranges. This behavior is supported by the option 'set pm3d clip z' (default). Smooth contour shapes using this feature are overlaid with a single-color fill corresponding to the palette.

This method has the disadvantage of increasing the file size in vector format because the pm3d surface is drawn over the number of contour levels. On the other hand, the file size does not become large when using pngcairo or other image output methods.

The script looks like this

```
set term pngcairo
set output "sample.png"

set view map
set xrange [*:*] noextend
set yrange [*:*] noextend
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10 

#
# set contour levels
#

cntrlist = "1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0"

#
# store contour line data to datablock "$contour"
#
unset surface
set contour 
set cntrparam level discrete @cntrlist
set zrange [*:*]
set table $contours
  splot 'matrix.dat' matrix
unset table
unset contours
set surface

#
# draw plot 
#
array cval = [@cntrlist]
mcval(k) = (cval[k]+cval[k+1])/2.0

set view map
set palette maxcolors ( |cval|-1 )
set cbrange [ cval[|cval|] : cval[1] ]
set zrange [ -10e300 : 0]

splot for [k=1:|cval|-1] \
         'matrix.dat' matrix using 1:2:($3-cval[k]) with pm3d fc rgb palette(mcval(k)) notitle, \
      $contours using 1:2:(0) with lines lc black notitle
```

[image]